# VueJS Using Vue.set on a nested array

Tags: vue.js

I know I can use `Vue.set` to modify a single element in an array:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

But how can I modify a single element in a nested array or nested object/array? Perhaps it my data looks like this:

```
data:{
      lists:[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]],
      another_list:[[213,123, {hello:'sdf'}], 12, 123]
}
```

How can I edit every single element reactively?

Comment: why don't you use methods object and loop through your array elements?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: For example modify the first nested element of lists: Vue.set('lists[0][0]', 2);

Answer (score 1):

This is for Vue.js `2.2.6`.

Assuming you are using single-file component `.vue`, you can use `this`.

For example: `this.lists[0][0] = 2`, will change the first value of first array to 2.

**Update**: due to the caveat with array, we need to use slice to update arrays. Read https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

```
<template>
 <button v-on:click="modify"> modify </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    methods: {
      modify: function() {
        console.log(this.lists)
        this.lists[0].splice(2,2,3) 
        console.log(this.lists)
      }
    }, 
    
  data: function () {
      return {
          lists:[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]],
          another_list:[[213,123, {hello:'sdf'}], 12, 123]
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

The console output will be

```
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
[[2,2,3],[2,3,4]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Will the reactivity work as well? For instance if I have `{list[0][0]}`, will it rerender?

Comment: I think you forgot the `s` instead of `method` it needs to be `methods`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Amr. 

Yes, the reactivity will work.

Comment: @user1506145 It seems that array does not get updated and will not rerender. This is weird because it works for other types like string. Will update you if I find something.

Comment: Asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243637/how-to-make-data-reactive-when-its-array-in-vue-template @user1506145

Comment: Then what are you using? Regardless, you should update your array this way `this.lists[0].splice(0,1,2) `

Comment: Yes, it works, please update the answer and put the correct answer at the top (delete the wrong answer). You have to splice on the last array it works regardless how deep it is, so if you render `{{list[2][3][0]}}` you can do this `list[2][3].splice(0,1,10)`. I'm writing components inline in javascript with template strings just as they do in the docs