# How to make data reactive when it's array in Vue Template

Tags: vue.js

```
<template>
  <button v-on:click="modify"> modify </button>
  <div v-model="lists">{{ lists[0] }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

 methods: {
    modify: function() {
      console.log(this.lists)
      this.lists[0][0] = 2
      console.log(this.lists)
    },

  data: function () {
    return {
      lists: [[1,2,3],[2,3,3]]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The array at template does not seems to get updated. But the log console has changed.

How do you make a data reactive when it's an array?

**What is actually happening:**

```
Before clicking modify
<div v-model="lists">{{ lists[0] }}</div> # produce 1
After clicking modify
<div v-model="lists">{{ lists[0] }}</div> #produce 1
```

**What is expected:**

```
Before clicking  modify
<div v-model="lists">{{ lists[0] }}</div> # produce 1
After clicking modify
<div v-model="lists">{{ lists[0] }}</div> #produce 2
```

Comment: @m_callens thanks for the catch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [caveat](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats) when updating arrays by index in Vue. Try this.

```
this.lists[0].splice(0,1,2)
```